# c++ vector.size() doesn't update if assigned through pointer

Tags: c++, c++11, vector

Just wondering, is there any way to update the size() when the vector is updated using pointer? Considering the following code

```
std::vector<int> test;
test.reserve(5);
int* pt = test.data();
for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i) {
    pt[i] = i;
}
for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i) {
    printf("%d ? %d\n", pt[i], test[i]);
}
printf("Size:%zu Capacity:%zu Empty:%u\n", test.size(), test.capacity(), test.empty());
for (auto i : test) {
    printf("Nothing:%d\n", i);
}
printf("END\n");
```

Numbers {0,1,2,3,4} are assigned to pointer (pt), and the vector (test) take up these values.
The output is

```
0 ? 0
1 ? 1
2 ? 2
3 ? 3
4 ? 4
Size:0 Capacity:5 Empty:1
END
```

The size remain as **0** and the for loop produce nothing.
I know there are easy way to fix this, like assign to the actual vector using [] or push_back().
But, just wondering, is there anyway to get/update the correct size()??

### EDIT

Maybe people pointed out using `resize()`, which only kind of do what I want to do (Sorry I wasn't clear at the original post).
Considering the following

```
std::vector<int> test;
test.resize(10);
int* pt = test.data();
int unknown_size = 5;  //This can be any unknown number which is < 10)?
                      //Long story short, save other space for later.
for (int i = 0; i < unknown_size; ++i) { 
    pt[i] = i;
}
for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i) {
    printf("%d ? %d\n", pt[i], test[i]);
}
printf("Size:%zu Capacity:%zu Empty:%u\n", test.size(), test.capacity(), test.empty());
```

Now we get `Size:10`. But we only used `5/unknown_size` elements. Are there any way get `.size() == 5`??
Yes, I realised that if I use `push_back()` then it solve all the problem. But is there anyway to do it with pointers?

Comment: `resize(5)`, not `reserve(5)`

Comment: You're invoking *undefined behavior*. `.reserve()` ensures when a resize is done (for whatever reason), the space is available up to the reserve. No such resize was done. You're access memory you don't technically own yet.

Comment: No, you are nvoking undefined behaviour by accessing `pt` out of bounds.

Comment: The problem still partially exist with `resize()`;
If I start with `test.resize(10)`;
then the `size()` will always be 10 regardless how many I assign.
So, is that possible to start with `test.resize(10)`; then assign 5 elements, and get `size() == 5`?

Comment: @Steven : no, it is not. `resize()` will set the size to 10. The bahvior that you desribe would use `push_back()` on the vector.

Comment: Are you sure you shouldn't be using std::array instead? there are too many ways that use of vector could go wrong.

Answer (score 7):

Your program has undefined behavior : Use `resize()` to change the size of the vector. `reserve()` only changes the **capacity**.

Answer (score 2):

You shoud use resize instead of reserve.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you simplified this code for the purpose of posting the question.

Please take into account the fact that vector.resize() invokes (default) constructor on the elements it had to create (requested - existing). If starting from scratch, you would have n Ctor invocations. If the cost is acceptable, by all means go ahead. Otherwise, you are better off combining reserve() + push_back(). And, you will get your exact size too.

Answer (score 0):

At the beginning of your code use `reserve()` to allocate memory for as many items as you reasonable expect.

If you are adding elements in order as you do in your example, use `push_back()` to add items to the vector. That will add one item to the end and update all the sizes. And, if you end up adding more items than you reserved, it automatically expands the vector.

An alternate way to go would be to call `resize()` at the beginning and then call `resize()` again at the end to shrink the vector size down.